# Concatenate multiple csv files in multiple folders based on Index_col based on multiple keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I have multiple folders and those folders have multiple csv files. How do I arrange my code to give the user the power of choosing folders (see example below) and combining the csv therein?

So, for example:
SA1, SA2, SA3 ,SA4 are folders and 2016_{filenumber}*AUS_SA1.csv, 2016*{filenumber}*AUS_SA2.csv, 2016*{filenumber}*AUS_SA3.csv, 2016*{filenumber}_AUS_SA4.csv are the csv files in each folder where {filenumber} is from 01 to 60.
I want to concatenate the csv files in individual folder with an index_col argument.
Those arguments for these files are SA1_7DIGITCODE_2016 (folder:SA1), SA2_MAINCODE_2016 (folder: SA2), SA3_CODE_2016 (folder: SA3) and SA4_CODE_2016 (folder: SA4) respectivley.

Following are my confused attempts:

```
selected_csv = []
region_select = ['SA1', 'SA2', 'SA3', 'SA4']
value_codes = [ 'SA1_7DIGITCODE_CODE','SA2_MAINCODE_2016', 'SA3_CODE_2016', 'SA4_CODE_2016' ]
edu_qual = "2016_{0}_AUS_SA1"
keywords = ['G01', 'G15', 'G16', 'G40', 'G46', 'G47', 'G48', 'G49', 'G50'] # User should define this
two_keys = dict(zip(region_select, value_codes))
```

This gives me:

```
>>> dict_values(['SA1_7DIGITCODE_CODE', 'SA2_MAINCODE_2016', 'SA3_CODE_2016', 'SA4_CODE_2016'])
```

which is good because that's what I want for index_col argument to combine each folder's files.

```
for i in keywords: 
    var_geo_select = geo_code.format(i, level)
    #print(var_geo_select)
    path_selection = os.path.join(path, var_geo_select+".csv")
    selected_csv.append(path_selection)
```

SA1 folder has 60 csv files with one of the headers being "SA1_7DIGITCODE_2016". Same for SA2 with "SA2_MAINCODE_2016" being one of the headers, so on and so forth for SA3, SA4. What I want to do is:

1. Let the user select which folder to go into.
2. If they select SA1, the the choice for index_col argument will be "SA1_7DIGITCODE_2016", if they select SA2, index_col choice will be "SA2_MAINCODE_2016"

How do I do this?
Sorry for the confused text, it's a bit hard to explain just in text. If you have any questions, I am happy to clarify.

Comment: Can you please add what the input data frame and result would look like ? Finding it hard to understand the context.

Comment: Deleting this question by tonight. Found a partial solution. 
You can see the newly framed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074101/how-to-read-csv-files-based-on-multiple-index-col-argument